# 100% of inner scroll box not the view box

Tags: html, css, kendo-grid

`100%` for element in scrollable container compute as 100% of viewbox not the real size.

You can see the the problem [in this Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uDELF) and in the following snippet:

```css
#container {
  max-width: 25em;
  background: #181818;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
#container #main td {
  background: #646464;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 5em;
}
#container #bottom {
  position: releative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  background: #cdc;
}
#container #bottom span:first-child {
  float: left;
}
#container #bottom span:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table id="main">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1111111</td>
        <td>2222222</td>
        <td>3333333</td>
        <td>4444444</td>
        <td>5555555</td>
        <td>6666666</td>
        <td>7777777</td>
        <td>8888888</td>
        <td>9999999</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="bottom">
    <span>0%</span>
    <span>100%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: what i see]

and i want this:

[image: what i want]

**EDIT:**
The real problem is about `Kendo grid`, so i can't change it's template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Without modifying HTML

I think the easiest solution is to remove the `#bottom` width and use Javascript to retrieve the width of `#main` and apply it to `#bottom`

### Javascript

```
//Create "tableWidth" variable from width of #main
var tableWidth = document.getElementById('main').offsetWidth;

//Set width of #bottom
document.getElementById('bottom').style.width = tableWidth+'px';
```

### Result

[image: Screenshot]

### Example Demo

Also [applied to your Codepen.](http://codepen.io/misterManSam/pen/dLIcg)

```js
//Create "tableWidth" variable from width of #main
var tableWidth = document.getElementById('main').offsetWidth;

//Set width of #bottom
document.getElementById('bottom').style.width = tableWidth+'px';
```

```css
#container {
  max-width: 25em;
  background: #181818;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
#container #main td {
  background: #646464;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 5em;
}
#container #bottom {
  position: releative;
  height: 2em;
  background: #cdc;
}
#container #bottom span:first-child {
  float: left;
}
#container #bottom span:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table id="main">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1111111</td>
        <td>2222222</td>
        <td>3333333</td>
        <td>4444444</td>
        <td>5555555</td>
        <td>6666666</td>
        <td>7777777</td>
        <td>8888888</td>
        <td>9999999</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="bottom">
    <span>0%</span>
    <span>100%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Old answer

Place the spans inside a tfoot td which has `colspan="9"` and style with `tfoot td`. Apply the existing td properties to `tbody td`.

### Example

Also [applied to your Codepen](http://codepen.io/misterManSam/pen/igGDB)

```css
#container {
  max-width: 25em;
  background: #181818;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
#container #main tbody td {
  background: #646464;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 5em;
}
tfoot td {
  height: 2em;
  background: #cdc;
}
tfoot span:first-child {
  float: left;
}
tfoot span:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table id="main">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1111111</td>
        <td>2222222</td>
        <td>3333333</td>
        <td>4444444</td>
        <td>5555555</td>
        <td>6666666</td>
        <td>7777777</td>
        <td>8888888</td>
        <td>9999999</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="9">
          <span>0%</span>
          <span>100%</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: tnx for your edit & answere, but i can't do this, because my real problem is about Kendo grid, and i can't change its template.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer. 2 lines of Javascript is the easiest answer here :)